# How to navigate back from FreshMasterDetailNavigationContainer with FreshMvvm?

Tags: xamarin.forms, freshmvvm

I use the following code to start a freshhmvvm master-detail page from a list in a navigation page. This works fine, but the user can not go back to the list page on IOS. On android it is possible using the system back-button from each detailpage.

Does this mean I have to add a 'Back' button to each detailpage to make this work on IOS? 
Or are there other ways to start a masterdetail in freshmvvm?

```
var masterDetailNav = new FreshMasterDetailNavigationContainer();
masterDetailNav.Init("Menu");
masterDetailNav.AddPage<FirstPageModel>("First", item);
masterDetailNav.AddPage<SecondPageModel>("Second", item.id);
await CoreMethods.PushNewNavigationServiceModal(masterDetailNav);
```

Comment: I worked around this by adding a ToolbarItem to each detail page, which calls CoreMethods.PopModalNavigationService() in its command.

Comment: I have the same problem for iOS and UWP. This means that PushNewNavigationServiceModal is not adding the new Navigation to the first navigation stack. Which is wrong and should be fixed. But it seems FreshMVVM development is dead. Ridland is not even updating the Nuget plugin with the latest git versions.